Can't connect to Mysql from Excel 64 bits with VBA
I try to migrate an Excel sheet that ran previously under Windows 10 with a 32 bits ODBC driver.
It seems my problem is not new since I read several questions about this.
I'm under Windows 11. I run Excel 64 bits and I installed MySQL ODBC Drivers 64 bits too.
If I use the query tool integrated to Excel, I can connect to my database with the ODBC driver.
I made a small test I pick up from an other thread:
Public Function OpenConnection() As ADODB.Connection
    Const location = "localhost"
    Const user = "swm"
    Const password = "xxxxxxx"
    Const database = "swm"
    Const mysql_driver = "MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver"

    ' Build the connection string
    Dim s As String
    s = "Driver={" & mysql_driver & "};Server=" & _
    location & ";Database=" & _
    database & ";UID=" & _
    user & ";PWD=" & password
    Debug.Print s
    
    ' Open connection
    Set OpenConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    OpenConnection.Open s
End Function

But I get the famous error:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I knew there was a trap with Excel 32 bits because ODBC 32 bits had to be installed. But there, all is in 64 bits.
Any help well come ! ;)

https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/on-64-bit-machine/?

@GSerg , thanks for the link. So, if I understand, I must install MySQL a MySql ODBCS Driver 32 bits, on my Windows 64 bits, with Excel 64 bits.
I downloaded ODBC 5.7 32 bits. But when I install it, this version seems not to be supported because it's not safe, too many bugs

No, what that link suggested is adding Provider=MSDASQL;.

Well, I found a solution.
I was a bit confused by everything I read about Excel, ODBC and MySQL with a 64 bits environment.
I made as well a mistake in the connect string.
Finally :

I installed the lasted MySQL ODBC ANSI Driver (version 8.3), 64 bits
I updated the driver parameter in the connect string with the right name of the driver !
No ODBC 32 bits driver !
No provider parameter

And it works !
